# How do I download or activate the community edition of Red Gate's MySQL Tools?

Tags: mysql, redgate

Red Gate [announced in April that they would be providing a free community edition of their MySql Tools](https://www.red-gate.com/blog/building/mysql-community-editions) - MySql Compare and MySql Data Compare.  I've previously installed trial versions of these tools and the trials have long since expired.  I'd like to use the community edition but haven't been able to find out how to get it.

When the tools start they display a "Your trial has ended" screen, with the only options being to Buy (which sends you to a broken URL), or to Activate which has no community option nor allows a blank input.  Are the community editions entirely different installers, or just a different licensing mode?

How do I use the community editions of the tools?  I've tried fully uninstalling and reinstalling them (in hopes of clearing the old trial data) without luck, and I haven't found any resources on Red Gate's site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you download the latest versions of these tools you will be asked to provide an email address. The new serial number will be emailed to you. This may take 2-3 hours.

If this doesn't work, please email me at David dot Atkinson at Red-gate dot com and I'll be happy to supply you with the serial number.

Comment: Thanks David, I found it in the original email from when my trial began

Comment: Great. Maybe we should make it more obvious! Hope you enjoy the tools. Please tell your friends and colleagues if you like them!